# Cómo resolver este error al usar ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Tengo un problema al correr una macro, al correr esta formula:

```
Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(value(RC[-1]),MonthlyProd.xlsb!MFG_YrMth[[#All],[YearWeek]:[YearMonth]],2,0)"
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(VALUE(RC[-1]),MonthlyProd.xlsb!MFG_YrMth[[#All],[YearWeek]:[YearMonth]],2,0)"
```

se supone que me debe arrojar el año con el mes de manufactura y el la otra celda, el año, solo lo hace con datos del 2017 hacia atras, del 2018 en adelante me sale #N/A

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como lo podria solucionar?

Comment: Un Vlookup tiene 4 argumentos, y tú estás metiendo cinco... `VLOOKUP(value(RC[-1]),MonthlyProd.xlsb!MFG_YrMth[[#All],[YearWeek]:[YearMonth]],2,0)` Entiendo que quieres traer la columna 2 del rango `MonthlyProd.xlsb!MFG_YrMth[[#All]`, pero no entiendo qué pinta en tu fórmula el `YearWeek]:[YearMonth]]`

Comment: eso YearWeek]:[YearMonth]] es donde busca los valores

Comment: Si eso es donde busca los valores, entonces qué es `MonthlyProd.xlsb!MFG_YrMth[[#All]`?

Comment: Ya pude, gracias.

Comment: Si encontraste una respuesta a tu propia pregunta, publícala y acepta tu propia respuesta para que la pregunta se pueda cerrar.